# For a contraction mapping $T$ with a fixed point $x$, prove $\lvert T^{n}x_{0} -x \rvert \leq \lvert T^{n}x_{0} - T^{m}x_{0} \rvert $ where $0<m<n$

Tags: fixed-points, contraction-operator

I am trying to follow a proof at the end of section 3.2 in [Hunter and Nachtergaele](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ebxn/applied_analysis.pdf) regarding the convergence of an algorithm to compute square roots. To prove that convergence is exponentially fast, the first step (page 67) is to show that the distance between the $n$-th iteration and the fixed point $x$ is less than or equal to the distance between any two points in $\left( x_{0}, Tx_{0}, T^{2}x_{0}, \ldots, T^{n}x_{0} \right)$.

I have tried expressing
$$
\begin{align}
  \lvert T^{n}x_{0} - x \rvert &\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lvert T^{n+i-1}x_{0}-T^{n+i}x_0 \rvert \\
  \lvert T^{m}x_{0} - T^{n}x_{0} \rvert &\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n-m}\lvert T^{m+i-1}x_{0}-T^{m+i}x_0 \rvert
\end{align}
$$

but I can't seem to perform a manipulation that gets me
$$ \lvert T^{n}x_{0} - x \rvert \leq \lvert T^{m}x_{0} - T^{n}x_{0} \rvert $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning with the definition of a contraction mapping $T$ and a fixed point $x$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
\lvert T^{n}x_{0}-x \rvert
&\leq c \lvert T^{n-1}x_{0}-x \rvert \\
&\leq c^{n-m} \lvert T^{m} x_{0} - x \rvert \\
&\leq c^{n-m} \left( \lvert T^{m} x_{0} - T^{n} x_{0} \rvert + \lvert T^{n} x_{0} - x \rvert \right) \text{.}
\end{align}
$$

Rearranging,
$$
\left( \frac{1}{c^{n-m}} - 1 \right) \lvert T^{n}x_{0}-x \rvert \leq \lvert T^{m} x_{0} - T^{n} x_{0} \rvert \text{.}
$$

We have $0 < c < 1$ and $n-m > 0$ so we have $\frac{1}{c^{n-m}} - 1 > 0$. In the special case where
$$
\frac{1}{c^{n-m}} - 1 \geq 1 \tag{1}
$$
we can write
$$
\lvert T^{n}x_{0}-x \rvert
\leq \left( \frac{1}{c^{n-m}} - 1 \right) \lvert T^{n}x_{0}-x \rvert
\leq \lvert T^{m} x_{0} - T^{n} x_{0} \rvert \tag{2} \text{.}
$$

In the example I was trying to figure out, we had $c=\frac{1}{2}$ so the condition for (2) to be true was $2^{n-m} - 1 \geq 1$ which is always true since $n > m$.

It turns out (1) (and consequently (2)) is *always* true when $c\leq\frac{1}{2}$. For $\frac{1}{2} < c < 1$, the condition (1) can be expressed in terms of $n-m$
$$
n-m> - \frac{\log 2 }{\log c} \text{.}
$$

For example, if $T$ contracts "slowly", $c=\frac{99}{100}$, we can still say
$$
\lvert T^{n}x_{0}-x \rvert \leq \lvert T^{m} x_{0} - T^{n} x_{0} \rvert
$$
if we restrict ourselves to $n-m \geq 69$.